# How to test VSCode extension with suggestions widget?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, vscode-extensions

I've read the [Official Guide: Testing Extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/testing-extension) and successfully run the [Demo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/helloworld-test-sample).

It seems that the examples from the demo are not related to the extension I am testing:

```
    test('Example test', () => {
        assert.strictEqual([1, 2, 3].indexOf(5), -1);
        assert.strictEqual([1, 2, 3].indexOf(0), -1);
    });
```

Let's say I want to test the extension of a programming language, I need to type code in the editor and check if the extension works, how do I do that?

For example, we need to open a file "a.rs" and type

```
enum IpAddrKind {
    V4,
    V6,
}


let four = IpAddrKind::
```

At this point, you should expect the editor to display the auto-complete list `[V4, V6]`.

[image]

In this case, we need to test if "V4" and "V6" are in the suggestions widget.

Comment: you can open a new file and use the `type` command to fill content, you don't have access to the pop-up window result, what you can test is call the completion provider in the extension and analyze its result. Most likely you are not writing the Rust Language provider, so assume that it works as expected

Comment: @rioV8 But if we are writing a extension for another programming language? Is there any demo project to help start testing like this case?

Comment: what popup window? the suggestions widget?

Comment: why do YOU need to test functionality of another extension, are you also testing all the functionality of VSC

Answer (score 0):

call the command [`vscode.executeCompletionItemProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands)

> `vscode.executeCompletionItemProvider` - Execute completion item provider.
>
> - *uri* - Uri of a text document
> - *position* - A position in a text document
> - *triggerCharacter* - (optional) Trigger completion when the user types the character, like `,` or `(`
> - *itemResolveCount* - (optional) Number of completions to resolve (too large numbers slow down completions)
> - *(returns)* - A promise that resolves to a CompletionList-instance.